# Calling a variadic template function gives error C2660 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, variadic-templates

The following code gives C2660 error in Visual Studio 2015 Community:

```
class Logger {
public:
    template <class T> void writeLine(const T& value) {
        if (this->filestream.is_open()) {
            filestream << object << std::endl;
        }
    }

    template <typename T> void write(const T& value) {
        if (this->filestream.is_open()) {
            filestream << value;
        }
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Targs> void write(const T& value, const Targs&... args) {
        if (this->filestream.is_open()) {
            filestream << value;
            this->write(args...);
        }
    }

    // ... singleton stuff
}
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
#define LOG(x) Logger::instance().write(__FILE__, " (line ", __LINE__, "): ", x, std::endl);
```

Here is the error in the output log:

```
encoder.cpp(51): error C2660: 'Logger::write': function does not take 6 arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `std::endl` is itself a template

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

Therefore a possible solution could be

```
var.write(__FILE__, " (line ", __LINE__, "): ", 22, std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
```

More information on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10015897/1938163)

Answer (score 1):

`std::endl` is a template, and the compiler doesn't have enough information to select an appropriate specialization. There are a multitude of ways to side step this:

- use `std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char>>` for your final argument (yuck).
- use `'\n'`, which obviously isn't equivalent, but will probably work.
- create a specialized `Logger::endl` and send that.

A decent example of the latter of these can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29324344/1322972).

---

Unrelated, you should probably consider using perfect forwarding regardless. It should be trivial to adapt your template members to do so.

```
template <typename T>
void write(T&& value) {
    if (this->filestream.is_open()) {
        filestream << std::forward<T>(value);
    }
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void write(T&& value, Args&&... args)
{
    this->write(std::forward<T>(value));
    this->write(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

See here: [Advantages of using `forward`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward), and the linked article, [The Forwarding Problem](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm).

Comment: I would have never guessed that the `std::endl` is making the problem. I used the first solution and it works perfectly. Why is perfect forwarding code better to use?

Comment: @AliAlidoust There are plenty of good references on the forwarding problem, and how perfect forwarding addresses it. See here: [Advantages of using `forward`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward), and the linked article, [The Forwarding Problem](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm). They'll explain it far better than I could.